# Memory leak with GDALOpen?

Tags: gdal

I'm very new in using GDAL, and trying the tutorial given [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html).

But with a piece of code with only

```
GDALRegister_GTiff();
GDALDataset  *poDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen(argv[1], GA_ReadOnly );

if( poDataset != NULL )
    GDALClose( (GDALDatasetH) poDataset );
```

Valgrind says there is a memory leak with 32 bytes still reachable. Is there a memory leak in the GDALOpen function?

**Edit**: Valgrind's output

```
==25399== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==25399==    at 0x4C2CC70: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25399==    by 0x660B68F: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:141)
==25399==    by 0x660B197: dlsym (dlsym.c:70)
==25399==    by 0x51A7F27: GTiffOneTimeInit (geotiff.cpp:10764)
==25399==    by 0x51B5382: GTiffDataset::Open(GDALOpenInfo*) (geotiff.cpp:6198)
==25399==    by 0x53C17E7: GDALOpenInternal(GDALOpenInfo&, char const* const*) (gdaldataset.cpp:2318)
==25399==    by 0x53C1A17: GDALOpenInternal(char const*, GDALAccess, char const* const*) (gdaldataset.cpp:2267)
==25399==    by 0x4010D7: main (main.cpp:18)
```

Line 18 is:

```
GDALDataset  *poDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen(argv[1], GA_ReadOnly );
```

However, I've followed the tutorial, and my program ends with:

```
/* Once we're done, close properly the dataset */
if( poDataset != NULL )
    GDALClose( (GDALDatasetH) poDataset );
```

I just observed that if I give a filename directly as a string in GDALOpen instead of using a command line parameter, I don't have the leak anymore.

Comment: This really belongs on gdal-dev

Comment: Are you sure that Valgrind is saying that the dataset is still reachable? The driver registration also brings things into memory, not to mention there are other things going on in the C runtime that Valgrind could be picking up depending on how you set it up.